# Getting data from the Java bean to be displayed on a JSP page

Tags: jsp, servlets, usebean

I've got a forum where a user can register there details and this gets sent to a Servlet and then a Java bean. What I'm having trouble with is that I can't get the data to be displayed on another JSP page when the Java bean is requested. So `CreateAccount.jsp` allows the user to input into the forum.

The forum is posted to a Servlet(`RegisterDetails.java`) and sends it to a Java bean (`Register.java`). Then `error.jsp` shows this data from the bean. Below is my code. The current code shows each value as `null`.

`Register.java`:

```
package com.cassandra.MrBlabber.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/Register")
public class Register extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Register() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RegisterDetails details = new RegisterDetails();
        details.setName(request.getParameter("FullName"));
        details.setEmail(request.getParameter("EmailAddress"));
        details.setPassword(request.getParameter("Password"));
        details.setUsername(request.getParameter("Username"));
        request.setAttribute("details", details);
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Error.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

`RegisterDetails.java`:

```
package com.cassandra.MrBlabber.servlets;

public class RegisterDetails  {
    private String fullName;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String password;
    private String username;

    public RegisterDetails() {}

    public String getName() { return fullName; }
    public String getEmailAddress() { return emailAddress; }
    public String getPassword() { return password; }
    public String getUsername() { return username; }

    public void setName(String value) { this.fullName = value; }
    public void setEmail(String value) { this.emailAddress = value; }
    public void setPassword(String value) { this.password = value; }
    public void setUsername(String value) { this.username = value; }
}
```

`CreateAccount.jsp`:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/MrBlabber/css/stylesheet.css"/>
<title>MrBlabber/Create an Account</title>
</head>
<body>      
    <!-- Section -->
    <section>
        <!-- Sign Up -->
        <article>
            <div id="articleWrapper">
                <h3>No Account? Sign Up</h3>
                <form id="createAccount" onsubmit="return validateForm();" action="Register" name="createAccount" method="POST">
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="FullName" placeholder="Full Name"/>
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="EmailAddress" placeholder="Email Address"/>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="Password" placeholder="Create a password"/>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="Username" placeholder="Choose your username"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign up for MrBlabber"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </article>

        <article>
            <div id="errorMessage" class="errorMessage">
                <script src="/MrBlabber/javascript/CreateAccountValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

`Error.jsp`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="com.cassandra.MrBlabber.servlets.RegisterDetails" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>shit</h1>

    <jsp:useBean id="RegisterDetails" class="com.cassandra.MrBlabber.servlets.RegisterDetails" scope="session"/>
    <jsp:setProperty name="RegisterDetails" property="*"/>
    <h1>
    Name: <%=RegisterDetails.getName()%><br>
    Email: <%=RegisterDetails.getEmailAddress()%><br>
    Password: <%=RegisterDetails.getPassword()%><br>
    Username: <%=RegisterDetails.getUsername()%><br>
    </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you're creating a new instance of `RegisterDetails` in your Servlet, the `<jsp:useBean>` tag is worth nothing. You can safely remove it. You can access the properties of the bean like, `((RegisterDetails)request.getAttribute("details")).getfullName()` and the same for the rest of the fields. Conventionally, the names of input fields should begin with a small case letter. Also, if you use JSTL/EL then, you can simply get the properties of `RegisterDetails` like `${details.fullName}`, `${details.emailAddress}`, `${details.password}` and `${details.username}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your class `RegisterDetails` is not a bean because it does not implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface.

Secondly, you really need to implement some kind of input sanitization for the data coming from the request (to prevent SQL/HTML/Cross-site scripting injections), and if you are going to use beans I guess you should put that inside the bean class.

Third, you could also dispense with the bean concept (meaning you won't need jsp:useBean) and just save the instance of the class RegisterDetails as a regular class object into the session, and then you can pull it from the session on any page as follows:

In the servlet:

```
 session.setAttribute("details", details); //saving your object to the session
```

In any other page:

```
RegisterDetails details = (RegisterDetails)session.getAttribute("details");
```

Comment: I was going to suggest this too. Something like:

       HttpSession session = request.getSession();
       RegisterDetails details = new RegisterDetails();
       details.setName(request.getParameter("FullName"));
       details.setEmail(request.getParameter("EmailAddress"));
       details.setPassword(request.getParameter("Password"));
       details.setUsername(request.getParameter("Username"));
       session.setAttribute("details", details);

Comment: He's already setting all the values in a variable details, but then is saving that in the request object rather than session object. So he can just change to saving it in the session object.

Comment: Since the request is just forwarded (not redirected using `response.sendRedirect()`), the object of `RegisterDetails` stored as a request attribute like `request.setAttribute("details", details);` can be available to JSP. There should not be necessary to store it into the session. Please don't mind.

Comment: The jsp business is all new to be and I'm trying to understand how jsp/servlets/beans are meant to interact before I get onto security and using a database. Anyway I will update my code with using session attribute as this now works. However, I would still like to know how I could still do the way I was doing it without a session. Thank you.

Comment: If you don't want to use the session, keep saving the bean in the request object in your servlet and forwarding to the JSP, then in the JSP do `RegisterDetails details = (RegisterDetails)request.getAttribute("details");'

Answer (score -2):

developerwjk - good catch on the bean not being serializeable, but that shouldnt cause the problem.

user3258979 - your servlet looks ok to me. And I can see your form doing the proper POST. Have you tried doing a trace on the servlet? Can you put a break point on this line to confirm the request values are coming through:

details.setName(request.getParameter("FullName"));

Comment: I have tested it so that you are able to print the values of the form from the servlet in the console. I have also tested it so if I were to use getUsername() from the bean it would also get the data.